# How to load form and load data synch ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to load data and form synch...
FIrst check my code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
      if (this.data.fromCalendar) {
        this.singleTraining();
      }
    }, 200); 
    this.formControl();
}


  formControl() {
    this.gibanjeAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.data.fromCalendar ? this.singleTrainingInfo?.name : '', Validators.required],
      description: [this.data.fromCalendar ? this.singleTrainingInfo?.description : ''
    })
  }


  singleTraining() {
    this.trainingService.getSingleTraining(this.data.fromCalendar.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.singleTrainingInfo = data; 
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

Here is problem asynch data....
I need to load in same time my form and my singleTraining request to show data.
If i not set example:

```
this.singleTrainingInfo?.name
```

example just set

```
this.singleTrainingInfo.description
```

i got error singleTrainingInfo not defined because is not loaded more... first i called form...I don;t know how solve this.

Must to load form and http in same ..

Answer (score 0):

`singleTrainingInfo` is set using `async` call, that means when you create `formControl` method. Async call isn't completed yet.

Ideally what you should do is, first create a form empty.

```
formControl() {
    this.gibanjeAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: []
    })
}
```

And as soon as the ajax call finishes, fill in the data inside the form using `patchValue` method.

```
singleTraining() {
    this.trainingService.getSingleTraining(this.data.fromCalendar.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.singleTrainingInfo = data;
        this.gibanjeAddForm.patchValue(data);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
}
```